# APC - SmartUPS RT 5000 Configuration

Tags: windows-server-2003, ups

I hope this is an easy one for someone!

We have a SmartUPS 5000 in our rack. At the moment, it looks like it's just been configured by our old IT support company to email them when it kicks in (not too useful).

I'd like to get it to shut down the servers we have here automatically on power interruption. I have a personal UPS at home, and I just install the software on the PC and after a few clicks, job done.

I understand this one works over the LAN. I can get access in to the web console however I can't work out what I need to do on the servers to get them to shut down once the UPS sends the command. I can't see any CD's about although I have registered on the APC site and have got some downloads. They all seem to want to look for serial or USB devices though.

Can anyone let me know what package I need to install to allow me to get this to work?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The product you need is called `Powerchute Network Shutdown` http://www.apc.com/products/family/index.cfm?id=127

Comment: I've just installed this thanks to your post. Looks like it should do the job. I take it this will act on the settings specified on the UPS device it's self (under UPS > Shutdown). I'll schedule in a planned test and see if they shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need some kind of master server that is issuing the shutdown command to the servers - I don't think you'll find this functionality on the UPS itself.

What package to install to do this will depend on what environment you have.  [PowerChute Network Shutdown](http://www.apc.com/products/family/index.cfm?id=127) looks like a likely candidate, but if you have some kind of network management system in place (e.g. Nagios based) you might be able to use that to issue shutdown when it detects that the UPS has kicked in.

Comment: If you see c10k's post, I've installed it and will do a test run. The UPS has shutdown parameters on it, how long to run on battery etc. so I'm thinking this might be what the software picks up. The installation asks for the management card IP, so it's talking to the UPS.

Comment: Yeah - c10k just pipped me to it.  Go with that one.